# Libavfilter with ffmpeg - overlay the last X seconds

Tags: ffmpeg

Looking at the docs of libavfilter it doesn't seem to be possible, but still, I hope you can help me.

I want to overlay an image to a movie but only for the last X seconds of the movie. I managed to overlay for the full movie, no problem. But can I get a time when the overlay is shown?

I use ffmpeg with compiled with libavfilter. Any tricks to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to FFmpeg developer Stefano Sabatini, this cannot currently be done.

> Right now you can't do that by using the overlay, you need a multi-steps
>   process, where you need to split the file, overlay just in the interested
>   segments and merge again the modified segments, or create an ad-hoc video to
>   overlay which shows the image only in the interested intervals.

[ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2012-January/004062.html](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2012-January/004062.html)